# Make Redux reducers and other non-components hot loadable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, flux, redux

I'm having a tough time getting my reducers to be hot swapable.

I'm using Webpack and `react-transform-hmr`. With this, all of the CSS and the components are hot loaded when I save, but when I try and work on another type of type - most notably the reducers - it would tell me to do a full refresh.

I figured out that this is because I need to explicitly re-load the reducers in and accept the event. Which I'm doing with this code in my `store.js`:

```
if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./reducers/', () => {
    const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index');
    store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
  });
}
```

`reducers/index` exports the root reducer.

However now when I run this it still tells me `[HMR] Cannot check for update (Full reload needed` and also errors saying `[HMR] TypeError: currentReducer is not a function`

So - I need some help getting this to work. The code is available at https://github.com/wesbos/Simple-Redux and you can reproduce it by doing:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm start`
3. Open localhost:3000 in your browser
4. Edit a reducer - open `posts.js` and change the number on line 6 to anything else

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I haven’t looked closely but my best guess is that it’s [this issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/issues/215#issuecomment-164185902).
Babel 6 no longer tries to make ES6 default exports the result of `module.exports`.

So instead of

```
const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index');
```

you probably want

```
const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index').default;
```

which matches the Babel 6 output for ES6 default exports.

Comment: That was it -Thank you!