# Using newer version of Redux, but Provider error still occurs on hot reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, babeljs

Edit: Updated and possibly clearer question here: [Adding react-hot-loader to ejected create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583395/adding-react-hot-loader-to-ejected-create-react-app)

When attempting to add hot reloading to **create-react-app** and use it with **Redux**, I get the following error:

[image]

I am creating my store using the [suggested pattern](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0). In the browser console, the `console.log` in `module.hot.accept` is never printed, but the `console.log("Hot!")` in the `if` statement is printed.

Information here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux"

import reducers from "./reducers"
import DevTools from "./devtools"

const enhancer = compose(
  DevTools.instrument()
)

export default function configureStore(initialState = { }) {
  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, enhancer)

  if (module.hot) {
    console.log("Hot!")
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      console.log("Attempting Redux hot reloading")
      const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store
}
```

I attempted to add `.default` behind `require('./reducers')` as [this suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243684/make-redux-reducers-and-other-non-components-hot-loadable?rq=1), but the error explained below still occurs.

My main app's render method is as follows. If I load the page without the `{undef}`, there are no errors. The word "Hot!" is displayed in the console. If I add the `{undef}` it hot reloads normally, shows no error, and shows an `undefined` error in the console. When I remove the `undef` the error is no longer shown, but the Provider error shown at the top happens.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Provider store={configureStore()} >

          <Router>
            <div>

              {undef}

              <DevTools />
              <Navigation />

              <Match exactly pattern="/"         component={Dashboard} />
              <Match exactly pattern="/meetings" component={Meetings} />
              <Match exactly pattern="/parking"  component={Parking} />

              <Miss component={Missing} />
            </div>
          </Router>

        </Provider>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am using the typical create-react-app supplied webpack loaders, with these alterations at the start of the `loaders` array.

[image]

The following are the versions of relevant npm packages I am using:

```
"react": "^15.3.1",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
"react-dom": "^15.3.1",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
"react-router": "^4.0.0-2",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
"babel-core": "6.14.0",
"webpack": "1.13.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "1.15.1",
```

Edit: I tried setting create-react-app up with the [changes shown here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/commit/64f58b7010a1b2a71ad16716eb37ac1031f93915), but it seems to just actually refresh the web page on changes, even if I am just editing a functional component.

Comment: I've never seen having two tests for a single extension, have you tried `{ test: /\.js$/, include: paths.appSrc, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'], query: require('./babel.dev') }` ?

Comment: Then I get the error "Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list"

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I've always used a `.babelrc` file in my root instead of the query. Can you add your `webpack.config.js` that shows us where you set up your webpack-dev-server?

Comment: This contains the default dev scripts for webpack and babel that I am using in my project: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/config

Comment: I am now trying to set it up using react hot loader 3, and I will make a new question for that. I have found out some more, but it is still not working.

Comment: @MarioTacke Updated question here. I think it is clearer to understand here. If you could help, I'd really appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583395/adding-react-hot-loader-to-ejected-create-react-app